# How to map specific row with NHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nhibernate

I have the following situation:

```
// Model Attribute
int Id;
string Name;
int Classification;
```

and

```
// Model Role
int Id;
string Name;
List<Attribute> Attributes;
```

Database looks like this:

```
tbl_Role
Id     Name
1      Admin
2      User
```

and

```
tbl_Attribute
Id     Name     Classification
1      Prename  1
2      Surname  2
```

and

```
tbl_Role_Attribute
RoleId ClassificationId
1      1
1      2
2      1
```

How can I create the mapping by code in NHibernate to get all allowed attributes for a role depending on the connected classification and resolve the attributes for JSON? How would the mapping for a model to the tbl_Role_Attribute look like? Something like:

```
public PolicyMapping()
    {
        Table("tbl_Role_Attribute");

        ManyToOne(a => a.Role, b =>
        {
            b.Column($"RoleId");
        });

        ManyToOne(a => a.Attribute, b =>
        {
            b.Column($"ClassificationId");
        });
    }
```

Expected JSON output from pseudo getRole()

```
[{Id: 1,
Name: Admin,
allowedAttributes: {
     Id: 1
     Name: Prename
     Classification: 1},
     {Id: 2
     Name: Surname
     Classification: 2}}]
```

If you need further information let me know. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

My target really is to map role to specific classifications (not every single attribute) and the get all attributes that are in that classification. (Imagine a classification like some sort of "group").

Answer (score 0):

You would map `Role` and `Attribute` and then have a `many-to-many` on `Role`. Something like (assuming FluentNhibernate):

```
public class AttributeMap : ClassMap<Attribute>
{
    public AttributeMap()
    {
        Id(a => a.Id);
        Map(a => a.Name);
        Map(a => a.Classification);
    }
}

public class RoleMap : ClassMap<Role>
{
    public RoleMap()
    {
        Id(r => r.Id);
        Map(r => r.Name);
        HasManyToMany(r => r.Attributes)
    }
}
```

Then you can create your JSON result like this:

```
var results = 
    session
        .Query<Role>()
        .Fetch(r => r.Attributes)
        .ToList();

var json = 
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
       results
           .Select(r => 
               new 
               {
                   r.Id,
                   r.Name,
                   allowedAttributes = r.Attributes
               });
```

Comment: How would that mapping look like? Sorry I'm a little newby to this.
Also I do not want an entry for every Role to Attribute in my tbl_Role_Attribute. That's one point of "grouping" them with classification

Comment: Thank you very much for that input! But unfortunately that's not for my case, because let's say `Role xy` has access to `Classification 1, 2 und 4`. The query would only work with a foreach AND I would have to map every Attribute to every Role. Any other ideas?

Comment: In the question, Role 1 has access to classification 1 & 2. Are you saying you want to constrain the classifications that it can have or find the roles that have certain classifications?

Comment: In your query in the `.Where` statement it gets only the attributes for classification 2. But as you said for Role 1 I would need those of classification 1&2